# How to take the value as array or convert it to array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

[My text area in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwbho.png)

[I am getting this value from text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFiq5.png)

[But i want something like this. As an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku0Ib.png)

The user can paste the array of objects in the text field and when they click the button the output should return unique values. In this case it should return 1 and 2. I have no issue in getting the output when i do it separately in JS file. The issue is i don't know how to get this value from text area as array of objects to be processed in my JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse JSON string. In JavaScript you can do this by:

`const obj = JSON.parse('{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');`

which will result with:

```
{
   name:"John",
   age:30,
   city:"New York"
}
```

[W3Schools JSON.Parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)